# Why am I getting E2BIG from exec() when I'm accounting for the arguments and the environment?

Tags: c, linux, exec

I have read a few pages (like [this one](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/)) about how to properly account for ARG_MAX on Linux.  As far as I can tell, each argument/environment var takes up the size of a pointer, and one plus its length for the nul-terminated string itself.  There's probably some extra room taken up by padding as well.  However, even after giving myself 2K of extra headroom, I'm still running into E2BIG when attempting to `exec()` a long command line.  What's causing this?

I thought it might be the [auxiliary vector](http://articles.manugarg.com/aboutelfauxiliaryvectors), but even adding its size (320 bytes in my case) doesn't help.  I'm also well below `MAX_ARG_STRINGS` and `MAX_ARG_STRLEN` (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120842/56202).

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

extern char **environ;

size_t arg_size(const char *arg) {
        // Count the string as well as the argv/environ pointer to it
        size_t size = sizeof(arg);
        if (arg) {
                size += strlen(arg) + 1;
        }
        return size;
}

int main() {
        size_t arg_max = sysconf(_SC_ARG_MAX);
        arg_max -= 2048; // POSIX recommends 2048 bytes of additional headroom
        printf("arg_max: %zu\n", arg_max);

        size_t size = 320; // For the auxiliary vector

        for (char **envp = environ; *envp; ++envp) {
                size += arg_size(*envp);
        }
        size += arg_size(NULL);

        char *argv[100001] = {"true"};
        size += arg_size(argv[0]);
        size += arg_size(NULL);

        char *arg = "0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF"
                    "0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF";
        size_t each_size = arg_size(arg);
        size_t i;
        for (i = 1; i < 100000 && size + each_size < arg_max; ++i) {
                argv[i] = arg;
                size += each_size;
        }
        argv[i] = NULL;

        printf("size: %zu, argc: %zu\n", size, i);
        assert(size < arg_max);

        execvp(argv[0], argv);
        perror("execvp()");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc e2big.c -o e2big && ./e2big
> arg_max: 2095104
> size: 2095059, argc: 28640
> execvp(): Argument list too long
> ```

For completeness, this is on

> ```
> $ uname -a
> Linux superluminal 4.13.7-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Oct 14 20:13:26 CEST 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux
> ```

Comment: counting the size of the pointer makes no sense, that said.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Sure it does, the `argv` array itself takes up space just like the data it points too.

Comment: I think he might mean that `sizeof(arg)` is the size of the pointer, not the size of the data it points to.

Comment: @WeatherVane ... but I'm counting both?

Comment: @WeatherVane nope, I saw that. OP is counting size of the pointer + size of the string + 1

Comment: @TavianBarnes have you tried reducing until it works? that could be interesting to know where _you_ find the limit

Comment: Oh ok, although he said counting the size of the pointer makes no sense.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I have, but that didn't help explain why what I'm already doing doesn't work.  I needed something like 4070 bytes of headroom in the worst case.

Comment: I'd toy with the size of arguments too (bigger for less arguments, see if the limit changes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out!  First, in addition to `argv[]` and `envp[]`, the `exec()` system call implementation also copies the full path to the executable for some reason, in a way that counts against E2BIG:

> ```
> retval = copy_strings_kernel(1, &bprm->filename, bprm);
> if (retval < 0)
>         goto out;
>
> bprm->exec = bprm->p;
> retval = copy_strings(bprm->envc, envp, bprm);
> if (retval < 0)
>         goto out;
>
> retval = copy_strings(bprm->argc, argv, bprm);
> if (retval < 0)
>         goto out;
> ```
>
> https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.13/fs/exec.c#L1775

Second, the argument strings are copied a page at a time, and only compared against the limit with the granularity of whole pages:

> ```
> unsigned long size = bprm->vma->vm_end - bprm->vma->vm_start;
> unsigned long ptr_size, limit;
> ...
> ptr_size = (bprm->argc + bprm->envc) * sizeof(void *);
> if (ptr_size > ULONG_MAX - size)
>         goto fail;
> size += ptr_size;
> ```
>
> https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.13/fs/exec.c#L222

So not only do I have to count the total lengths of the argument/environment strings, I have to round that up to a multiple of the page size before adding the size of the pointers.  Or, for simplicity, just make sure I give at least an entire page of headroom.

Answer (score -1):

```
    char *argv[100000] = {"true"};
    ....
    for (i = 1; i < 100000 && size + each_size < arg_max; ++i) {
            argv[i] = arg;
            size += each_size;
    }
    argv[i] = NULL;
```

Welcome to UB world. Upon the termination of the loop, `i` is 100000, and you are no supposed to touch `argv[100000]`.

*Pure speculation: the `argv` array is allocated on the stack, and only compiler knows how that one-off element is mutilated by `printf`*.

Comment: Admittedly a mistake, but the loop breaks early at iteration 28640 anyway, so that can't be the cause!

Comment: It sure could be. If that NULL gets overwritten (as it could be, since `argv[100000]` is "borrowed memory"), `argv` is no longer terminated where you think it is.

Comment: Not sure what you mean here... when I run this code, the `size + each_size < arg_max` condition is `false` when `i == 28640`, so the loop breaks early and `i` is never equal to 100000, so `argv[100000]` is never accessed.  Anyway I fixed the code in the question so there's no chance of an out-of-bounds access.